# Headers missing from XMLHttpRequest on iOS UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, xmlhttprequest

I'm experincing an odd situation where I have some JavaScript code running in a UIWebView. That JS code creates and fires off an `XMLHttpRequest` to pull some data off a server.

I listen for `onreadystatechange` and I have an event listener for the `"progress"` event.
For some reason this `XMLHttpRequest` returns only a subset of the Response Headers when queried using `request.getAllResponseHeaders()` or `request.getResponseHeader('whatever')`. Note that I've tried GETting any number of different of URLs and they all exhibit the same partial lack of headers.

The only headers returned are `Pragma, Cache-Control, Expires & Content-Type`, nothing else returns (content-length, encoding, various custom headers, etc).

The odd thing is that the same JS code executed in Mobile-Safari will show all the headers, in strike contrast to how that code behaves when inside a UIWebView.

Any idea what's going on here?